# How to send fetch post request to an API key based authorized endpoint?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a .netcore web API application with several endpoints and I have a simple UI built to access an endpoint with a button click using javascript fetch API.

```
 fetch('api/Sessions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(callData)
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => updateResponse(response))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Now the API endpoint in the controller is authenticated with API-KEY,  `[ServiceFilter(typeof(AuthorizeKey))]` I can no longer access the endpoint from my UI. How can I change the HTML/javascript code in order to send the post request from my UI to the authenticated endpoint?
Thanks

Comment: Please do not tag your questions with language tags not related to your problem

Comment: You would do this using the [HTTP Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization), but for that we need to know what kind of authorization your server is doing, is it bearer token auth? If so, then you need the header `'Authorization': 'Bearer <insert api key here>`

Comment: In the API, we are getting the API secret key from the header as `context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-API-KEY"];`. Therefore as per my understanding is it possible to add the key in the header and how to add it if it's possible?

Comment: Yes, your client side would simply need to add the "X-API-KEY" header to the request, with the value of your API key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
fetch('api/Sessions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-API-KEY': 'apikey',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(callData)
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => updateResponse(response))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```